# ayuda html y css

Tags: html, css

espero esten bien.
tengo el siguiente problema con mi menu desplegable hecho en html con css

como puedo hacer para que mi primer sub menu se mire el segundo que muestro en la imagen.

[image: el primer sub menu se mira muy a la izquierda, quiero quede como la segunda imagen]

[image: imagen de como quiero se mire el primero]
dejo el codigo html y css para si tengo algun problema.

CSS

```
* {
                margin:0px;
                padding:0px;
            }

            #header {
                margin:auto;
                width:100%;
                font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            }

            ul, ol {
                list-style:none;
            }

            .nav {
                width:100%; /*Le establecemos un ancho*/
                margin:0 auto; /*Centramos automaticamente*/
            }

            .nav >li {
                float:left; 
                width:140px; 
            }

            .nav li a {
                background-color:#000;
                color:#fff;
                text-decoration:none;
                padding:10px 12px;
                display:block;
            }

            .nav li a:hover {
                background-color:#434343;
            }

            .nav li ul {
                display:none;
                position:absolute;
                min-width:140px;
            }

            .nav li:hover > ul {
                display:block;
            }

            .nav li ul li {
                position:relative;
            }



            .nav li ul li ul {
                right:-140px;
                top:0px;
            }
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="prueba.css">
    <title>MDI</title>
</head>
<body>

        <div id="imagenes">
        <img src="logo1.jpg" style="width:300px;height:100px;">
        <img src="logo2.jpg" style="width:300px;height:100px;">
        </div>


    <!--Contenido-->
    <div id="header">

     <!--Listas-->
     <nav>
    <ul class="nav">

     <li><a href="">Inicio</a></li>

     <li><a href="">Registro</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="">Ingreso de expediente</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Busqueda de expediente</a>
           <ul>
            <li><a href="">No. Expediente</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Nombre Establecimiento</a></li>
           </ul> 
        </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="">Tramitaciones</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="">Faces del Proceso</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Tipo de certificado</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="">Primera vez</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Renovacion</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li> 
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="">Reportes</a>
        <ul class="sub_menu">
        <li><a href="">Reporte Mensual</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Reporte Trimestral</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Reporte Anual</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

     <li><a href="">Mantenimiento</a></li>

     <li><a href="">Usuario</a>
        <ul class="sub_menu">
        <li><a href="">Cuenta</a></li> 
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Gracias por su ayuda :)

Comment: En principio siempre que usas floats, utiliza el clearfix, para limpiar.

Answer (score 0):

Muy buenas no se si te refieres a que se vean igual sin que se pise uno al otro? en tal caso modifica a uno mas grande tu valor rigth de

```
        .nav li ul li ul {
            rigth:-140px;
            top:0px;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

He estado investignado un poco, pero no he ehcontrado como hacerlo dinámico con css. Lo he hecho con `JavaScript`. He modificado algunos apartados de tu codigo. Aqui viene:

```js
window.onload = function () {
  //aqui hacemos el evento de abrir los <li>
  for (let boton of document.querySelectorAll(".nav li")) {
      boton.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
          //le damos la posibilidad de mostrar
          try {
              this.children[1].style.visibility = "visible";
              //si tiene hijos, osea el menus desplegable extra, que le de los valores necesarios
              isMasMenuDesplegable(this);
          } catch (e) {}
      });
      boton.addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
          try {
              //quitamos la posibilidad de mostrar
              this.children[1].style.visibility = "hidden";
          } catch (e) {}
          //utilizamos try - cacth para evitar errores, por ejemplo intentarr mostrar un <ul> inexistente
      })
  }

  //Este metodo comprubea si hay mas hijos, si los hay, los muestra de forma que tu quieres
  function isMasMenuDesplegable(elemento) {
      if (elemento.children[1].children) {
          for (let boton of elemento.children[1].children) {
              boton.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
                  try {
                      this.children[1].style.visibility = "visible";
                      //al elemento <li> le damos right (right completo del padre)
                      this.children[1].style.right = "-" + (this.parentNode.offsetWidth) +
                          "px";
                      //al elemento <li> le damos el top concreto (top del padre)
                      this.children[1].style.top = "-" + (this.parentNode.children[
                          0].offsetHeight) + "px";
                          //es recursiva, es decir, si hay mas hijos, estos hijos se mostraran correctamente
                      isMasMenuDesplegable(this);
                  } catch (e) {}
              });
              boton.addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
                  try {
                      this.children[1].style.visibility = "hidden";
                  } catch (e) {}
              })
          }
      }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
  }

  #header {
      margin: auto;
      width: 100%;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }

  ul,
  ol {
      list-style: none;
  }

  .nav {
      width: 100%;
      /*Le establecemos un ancho*/
      margin: 0 auto;
      /*Centramos automaticamente*/
  }

  .nav>li {
      float: left;
      width: 140px;
  }

  .nav li a {
      background-color: #000;
      color: #fff;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 10px 12px;
      display: block;
  }

  .nav li a:hover {
      background-color: #434343;
  }

  .nav li ul {
      visibility: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      min-width: 140px;
  }

  .nav li ul li {
      position: relative;
  }

  .nav li ul li ul {
      position: relative;
  }
```

```html
<div id="imagenes">
    <img src="logo1.jpg" style="width:300px;height:100px;">
    <img src="logo2.jpg" style="width:300px;height:100px;">
</div>


<!--Contenido-->
<div id="header">

    <!--Listas-->
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav">

            <li><a href="">Inicio</a></li>

            <li><a href="">Registro</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Ingreso de expediente</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Busqueda de expediente</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">No. Expediente</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Nombre Establecimiento</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="">Tramitaciones</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Faces del Proceso</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Tipo de certificado</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">Primera vez</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Renovacion</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="">Reportes</a>
                <ul class="sub_menu">
                    <li><a href="">Reporte Mensual</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Reporte Trimestral</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Reporte Anual</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="">Mantenimiento</a></li>

            <li><a href="">Usuario</a>
                <ul class="sub_menu">
                    <li><a href="">Cuenta</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Ya se que puede parecer difícil o demasiado complicado, pero sol es investigar un poco. Cualquier duda, pregunta!

Comment: muchas gracias :)

Comment: Te ha servido? Te ha funcionado como aquí en el ejemplo?